# R: Large dataframe: Need to sort all elements and then output with position info

Tags: r

I have a large (500 * 21000) dataframe consisting of numeric values. I would like some help in doing this task most efficiency:
Essentially, I would like to sort the items in the dataframe, get an O/P with index information. i.e. If the largest element, say is  I would also like to know its  (position) in the dataframe. I need info on all elements in the dataframe - not just the largest/smallest (in which case I could easily get that info from the summary call).
I can think of ways to program this - but I am wondering if there is some built in utilityin R to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: I know it's annoying when people ask this, but... Why? There may be easier ways to deal with this, depending on what you want to do next.

Comment: No example code. No specified correct answer. Use of undefined abbreviations. In short, a poor question. Please do improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. But this can be a starting point for you.

```
> set.seed(345)
# Create a dataframe
> newdf <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n=100,mean=2.5,sd=2.5),
+                     y = rnorm(n=100,mean=4.5,sd=10),
+                     z = rnorm(n=100,mean=3.8,sd=1))
> head(newdf)
          x          y        z
1 0.5377296 -9.1446883 3.008115
2 1.8012141 -0.3508551 3.681795
3 2.0963553 13.3248010 4.116340
4 1.7735086  3.0728637 5.545473
5 2.3311710 -5.3247035 3.733314
6 0.9161990  9.3002188 3.763627
> 

# Find the maximum on each column
> sapply(newdf,max)
        x         y         z 
 9.545697 31.851232  5.956058 
# Find the location of maximum value on each column
> sapply(newdf,which.max)
 x  y  z 
85 87 79
```